# jquery menu and IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this menu:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
$("html").addClass("js");
$.fn.accordion.defaults.container = false; 
$(function() {
  $("#acc3").accordion({initShow : "#current"});
  $("#acc1").accordion({
      el: ".h", 
      head: "h4, h5", 
      next: "div", 
      initShow : "div.outer:eq(1)"
  });
  $("#acc2").accordion({
      obj: "div", 
      wrapper: "div", 
      el: ".h", 
      head: "h4, h5", 
      next: "div", 
      showMethod: "slideFadeDown",
      hideMethod: "slideFadeUp",
      initShow : "div.shown"
    });
  $("html").removeClass("js");
});
//--><!]]>
</script> 
<!--<![endif]--> 

    <div id="menuesq_container">
<div id="main">
    <div class="marcadorMenuEsq">
    <h2 class="hMarcador">Produtos</h2></div> 
    <div id="acc2" class="accordion"> 
                        <h4>Panelas</h4> 
                        <div class="inner"> 
                            <h5>PanelaA</h5> 
                            <div class="inner"> 
                              <p>Panela1</p>
                              <p>Panela11</p>
                              <p>Panela12</p>
                              <p>Panela13</p>
                            </div> 
                            <h5>PanelaB</h5> 
                            <div class="inner"> 
                               <p>Panela2</p>
                               <p>Panela21</p>
                               <p>Panela22</p>
                               <p>Panela23</p>
                          </div> 
                               <p>Panela3</p>
                               <p>Panela31</p>
                               <p>Panela32</p>
                               <p>Panela33</p>
                          </div> 
                          <h4>Faca</h4> 
                          <div class="inner shown"> 
                              <h5>FacaA</h5> 
                              <div class="inner"> 
                                  <p>Faca1</p>
                                  <p>Faca12</p>
                                  <p>Faca13</p>
                              </div> 
                              <h5>FAcaB</h5> 
                              <div class="inner"> 
                                  <p>Faca2</p>
                                  <p>Faca22</p>
                                  <p>Faca23</p>
                              </div> 
                          </div> 
                          <h4>Frigideira</h4> 
                          <div class="inner"> 
                              <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> 
                <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> <p>Frigideira1</p>
                <p>Frigideira12</p>
                <p>Frigideira13</p>
                <p>Frigideira14</p>
                <p>Frigideira15</p>
                <p>Frigideira16</p> 
                          </div> 
                    </div> <!-- end Accordion 2 --> 
                </div> 
            </div>
    </div></div>
```

It works fine on Chrome, FF, Safari and on IE9. the problem is IE6, IE7 and IE8 the navigation gets hidden . I'm testing on IE6 and when I delete the Internet temporary files the menu magically appears without refresh the page.

[This is the JQ accordion that I use](http://www.adipalaz.com/scripts/jquery/jquery.nestedAccordion.js)

[this is the Test Site Link](http://www.fastcommerce.com.br/home.asp?IDLoja=12929&Y=1104933001100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was about this css style:

```
.js #main .accordion {visibility:hidden}
```

I only deleted this and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

the error seems to take place in IE quirksmode (IE 7-9 standard modes do show the menu)

both Chrome and IE are throwing an error: `Autocomplete is not defined`

I don't think the issue is the accordian, try removing/fixing the following to see if the accordian works in IE6+

```
new Autocomplete('query', { 
    serviceUrl:'BuscaTermosProd.asp?IDLoja=12929',
    minChars:2,
    maxHeight:300,
    width:370,
    deferRequestBy:500,
    showResults:1,
    autoSubmit:false,
   onSelect: function(value, data){
     document.buscaprod.Texto.value=value;
     document.buscaprod.submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have to fix a conflict with another script to be able to use Autocomplete, but I have deleted it at the moment and the problem continues yet. 
The very bad issue is that I have to work in quirksmode because the Ecommerce provider doesn't work with html declarations. 

I don't know if  htere is a trick to force a declaration.

Comment: I tried to set the menu display:block, inline-block... nothing, the menu doesn't appear yet. Please give me some idea. I'm blocked.

Comment: if you disable the `alert()` that pops up on page load does the menu show up?